# Macro and function with same name

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following code

```
#define myfunc(a,b) myfunc(do_a(a), do_b(b))

void myfunc(int a, int b)
{
  do_blah(a,b);
}
int main()
{
    int x = 6, y = 7;
    myfunc(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

I want the pre-processor to expand function myfunc only at calling. Required  code after pre-processing looks like this:

```
void myfunc(int a, int b)
{
  do_blah(a,b);
}
int main()
{
    int x = 6, y = 7;
    myfunc(do_a(x),do_b(y));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that function definition is expanded also like this

```
void myfunc(do_a(int a), do_b(int b))
{
  do_blah(a,b);
}
```

Is there any way to make macro expands only if we are expanding a function call?
I tried many solutions, and it seems impossible but I hope that some one saw situation like this..

NOTE: please don't tell me to rename the macro or function names :D

Update1:
Thanks for you help. But I can only change the definition of the macro, I can't change its position and I can't change function implementation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `()` to stop the preprocessor from expanding the function definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define myfunc(a, b) myfunc(do_a(a), do_b(b))
/* if you have a preprocessor that may be non-standard
 * and enter a loop for the previous definition, define
 * myfunc with an extra set of parenthesis:
#define myfunc(a, b) (myfunc)(do_a(a), do_b(b))
 ******** */

int (myfunc)(int a, int b) /* myfunc does not get expanded here */
{
    printf("a=%d; b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

int do_a(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

int do_b(int b)
{
    return b - 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    myfunc(4, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think some preprocessors may balk at the the recursive use of the form myfunc(xxx,xxx).  I'd do

#define myfunc(a,b) (myfunc)(do_a(a), do_b(b))

int (myfunc)(int a, int b)
&c

Comment: Good point, Tim, thanks! But I think it's safe to assume the preprocessor will never enter a recursive loop (cf Standard 6.10.3.4/2 "... if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced ...").

Comment: If you can change the function to put () around it's name, why can you not change the function's name?

Comment: I've been wondering about that too, but didn't have the guts to ask the question directly :)

Comment: To change the function's name you have to 
- get approval from all the managers
- update all documents
- re-run test cases

Comment: FWIW this didn't work for me on g++ 11.4.0; I had some code importing `<ncurses.h>`, which #defined OK (0), and was struggling to also define my own `bool OK();`, even with the suggested fix to wrap with parantheses: `bool (OK)()`. Ultimately I had to `#undef OK`, as we were fortunately not using that

Comment: @BentHam it didn't work for you because your macro definition of `OK` is not a *function-like* macro definition. Would have worked if ncurses had something like `#define OK(x) ((x)?0:0)`

Answer (score 9):

I see three possible solutions:

- define your macro after function definition.
- define, before the function definition, `do_a()` and `do_b()` such that they return their argument, and redefine them at your will after function definition
- perform `do_a()` and `do_b()` inside the function:

  ```
  void myfunc(int a, int b)
  {
      do_blah(do_a(a),do_b(b));
  }
  ```

I have a strong preference for the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Define the macro *after* the defintion of the function.

```
void myfunc(int a, int b)
{
  do_blah(a,b);
}

#define myfunc(a,b) myfunc(do_a(a), do_b(b))

int main()
{
    int x = 6, y = 7;
    myfunc(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the macro after you define the function.

Alternatively, use a pattern like this:

```
#define myfunc_macro(a,b) myfunc(do_a(a), do_b(b))
#define myfunc(a,b) myfunc_macro(a,b)

.
.

#undef myfunc
void myfunc(int a, int b)
{
  do_blah(a,b);
}
#define myfunc(a,b) myfunc_macro(a,b)

.
.

int main()
{
    int x = 6, y = 7;
    myfunc(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```