# C macro to only change function calls and not function definitions

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a very similar question to: [Macro and function with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951885/macro-and-function-with-same-name)

I want a macro to only change the function call and not the function itself

```
#define original_function(a, b) replace_function(a, b)

uint64_t replace_function(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

uint64_t original_function(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

uint64_t main(uint64_t argc, uint64_t* argv) {
    original_function(10, 20);
}
```

this would result in changing the original function definition

```
#define original_function(a, b) replace_function(a, b)

uint64_t replace_function(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

uint64_t replace_function(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

uint64_t main(uint64_t argc, uint64_t* argv) {
    original_function(10, 20);
}
```

I cannot do this (which is the answer in the linked question)

```
uint64_t (original_function)(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

//...
```

And I cannot put the definition after the function

```
uint64_t original_function(int a, int b) {
    // some functionality
}

#define original_function(a, b) replace_function(a, b)

// ...
```

Is it somehow possible to define in the macro to only change function calls and not function definitions?
Or can I somehow define a macro to rename only the original function (not the call) so it won't be affected?

**Edit:**
I can only change the macro not the code after that...

Comment: Why can't you  put the definition after the function? What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you thought about using function typedefs and then you can change the variable before calling it, makes for more readable code.

Comment: @J...S I cannot put the definition after the function because I will need to have the macro passed as argument to the compiler

Comment: @LDK 'Macro passed as argument to the _compiler_'? How

Comment: @J...S `gcc -D'original_function(a,b)=replace_function(a,b)' ... `

Comment: Do not `-D'original_function(a,b)=replace_function(a,b)'` when code compiles `original_function()`.

Comment: @Neil thanks it migth work for others but I can really only change the macro...

Comment: Perhaps if the higher level goal was stated?  What is desired is unusual, yet a different approach will likely solve the higher issue - if we knew it.

Comment: Can you use `#undef`?

Comment: @Cornstalks I could use `#undef` but only at the very top not between the functions etc.

Comment: @chux I'm not sure what you mean? I can apply the marco only when I compile the whole code...

Comment: @chux The goal is: I have a c-file (which I cannot change) which executes a functions and through a marco passed to the compiler I want it to execute a different function...

Comment: "I could use #undef but only at the very top not between the functions etc." --> Why this limitation?  Any goals and limitations should be appended to the post.

Comment: @chux Because I am passing the marco to the compiler without changing the code

Comment: Is  the code that defines `original_function()` in one .c file and the code the uses `original_function()` in other .c files?

Comment: @chux no all code is in the same .c file

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect you are [out-of-luck](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+luck).

Comment: Is the linkage name of the original function important? If not, you could use a conditional definition of the `original_function` macro, like: `#ifndef original_function`, `#define original_function(a, b) the_original_function(a, b)`, `#endif`, and change `uint64_t original_function(int a, int b)` to `uint64_t the_original_function(int a, int b)`.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for your input but I tried it and this also just changes the name of the function definiton and name the function call

Comment: @LDK True. My suggestion was just to supply a default replacement when none has been provided via macro definitions on the command line. Because otherwise, you're out of luck as chux mentioned, as there is no way to temporarily undefine a macro and restore it later if you don't know the original macro definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "pattern match" the line that the definition is on using the C preprocessor.  To do this in a useful fashion, first you need an indirect `SECOND` macro:

```
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(A,B,...) B
```

...then it's useful to have an indirect `GLUE`:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
```

...and finally, "selectively blue paint" `original_function` onto itself if and only if it appears on a specific line (this approach requires figuring out which line it's on, but I would suggest not being picky with this strange request):

```
#define original_function(a,b) \
   SECOND(GLUE(EXCEPT_FOR_LINE_,__LINE__),replace_function)(a,b)
```

So this macro will expand `original_function` with two arguments with `replace_function`, given that the first constructed token is not defined.  But if that first token is defined, then the token expands first, after which the second argument for *that* is selected.  Which means, you get to do this:

```
#define EXCEPT_FOR_LINE_6 ,original_function
```

...and if original_function is actually defined on line 6 (and not called on line 6), then the final expansion looks like the original... on line 6; and on all other lines it will generate a call to `replace_function`.

[This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49c505a2306a58bd) uses this technique on your code.  And as a bonus, all of the macros above in this example are defined on the command line (per your reflected intended usage in the comments).