# What does it happen if I declare a function already declared in a included header file in C?

Tags: c

Let us suppose the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int abs(int x){
    return x*2;
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",abs(-2));
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and execute it, I noticed that the abs function of math.h is being used. Actually, this happens even if I remove the #include <math.h>. But I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: `abs` is probably a defined macro.

Comment: Using `#include <math.h>`, you _will_ get a conflict at _compile_ time (an error). But, if you remove it, there shouldn't be an issue. And, unless you're doing `-lm`, most compilers/linkers will _not_ include (e.g.) `libm.so` by default. There may be exceptions for some compilers. And, even so, the linker should favor _your_ `abs` code because it's in the same `.c` file. So, as Daniel asked, what compiler, linker, libc/libm are you using on what system (e.g. linux, *BSD, etc.)?

Comment: When I try this with MSVC it is plain that the function is used.

Comment: Related: [Macro and function with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951885/macro-and-function-with-same-name).

Comment: @Craig Estey, Re "*Using `#include <math.h>`, you will get a conflict at compile time (an error)*", [Not with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Ybd1K33xn)

Comment: The standard library function `int abs(int x);` is declared in `<stdlib.h>` (not `<math.h>`).  But given the constant argument, the compiler is probably evaluating the result of `abs(-2)` at compile time.  Try using a loop with a variable argument to `abs()` and see what happens.

Comment: @Daniel A. White gcc on Linux exhibits the behaviour described.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Re "*Try using a loop with a variable argument to abs() and see what happens.*", [No change](https://godbolt.org/z/MMf179boT)

Comment: @ikegami: yes — judging from the generated assembler (and the program behaviour), it does seem that GCC knows how to use `abs()` without calling the library function (or any other function than `printf()`) — it uses a single instruction to do the job on an x86/64 machine.  Moral: don't try overriding the standard C library functions — it may not work.

Comment: Actually, it can be two instructions — a `neg` and a `cmov` instruction; but still quicker than an actual function call and return by a large margin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `abs` is not declared in `math.h` only `stdlib.h`.
2. GCC uses built-in abs and ignores your code.
3. You need to use `-fno-builtin` flag and the program will behave your way.

[image]

https://godbolt.org/z/v9xM3jbbj